# I'm trying to send a form on my wordpress website using ajax, but its an error 500

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, http-status-code-500

The form is created using Contact Form 7, but the submit action is made with AJAX and a file php which made a database conection, the error return: 500 (Internal Server Error) on php file and: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).AjaxDebug is not a function on AJAX function.

In the debug file generated by WP there is nothing related with this error.

someone can help me to understand this problem?

I disabled the plugins one by one, hoping for the problem is a conflict, but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

you clean the cache?! use a plugin like Super Cache good luck

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, actually didn't work.